# JQuery show/hide whithout hard coded id

Tags: jquery

I wanna make jQuery function to show/hide some elements (now it is `<li>`);

**So, I have this code:**

```
.sub {
    display: none;
}

 ....

$(function show_sub(id) {
    $('#'+id).show('fast');
});

 .....

<a href="" onmouseover="show_sub('id1')" onclick="return false;"> Here is it </a> 
<li id="id1" class="sub"> .... </li>
```

On the Internet, I only found functions where I must hard code the id of the element.

I know my jQuery function is incorrect.

Please, help me!

Comment: I mean, if you want to only hide that one li element, you are going to have to be able to uniquely identify it in some way. It does not have to be using an id of course. It could be the location in the list, and many other properties. You would have to give some more information about it to help out more.

Comment: Can you show (a sample of) some actual HTML you're using? How do the `a` elements relate to the `li` elements?

Comment: You need to actually *define* the `show_sub()` function, rather than passing it to `$()` (which is short for `$(document).ready()`). Just remove the jQuery part and it should work. And a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fE8VP/).

Answer (score 4):

You could clean a bit your code doing like so

Html

```
<a href="#"> Here is it </a> 
<li class="sub"> .... </li>
```

Javascript

```
$(function() {
    $('a[href="#"]')
       .on('hover', function() {
           $(this).next('li').show('fast'); // or toggle();
       })
       .on('click', function(ev) {
           ev.preventDefault()
       })
});
```

Doing so you can avoid useless markup, redundant information and inline handlers.

Example Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GYye8/

Answer (score 1):

You need to get element you want to show/hide.
Getting it by id is one way, but there are many more.

Look at [jquery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

For example you can show element with "sub" class by:

```
$(".sub").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("li.sub").show()` shows all `li`'s with class `sub`.

Is that what you´re after?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below

**html**

```
<a href="#" class="li-toggler" data-toggle="id1">li toggler</a>   
<li id="id1">sometext</li>​
```

**js**

```
$("a.li-toggler").click(function() {
   $("#"+$(this).attr("data-toggle")).toggleClass("sub");
});
```

​